# Call for Bibtex fails

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, linux

I am having problems when I try to run bibtex with both TEXmaker and in the terminal. I'm using centOS.

In w8 everything runs ok, and I get the final pdf with correct references.

In Linux though, with TEXmaker I get

```
Error : could not start the command
```

when I try to compile, either by doing it manually or with quickbuild. I compile by doing latex+bibtex+latex+latex.

In the terminal my bash script looks like this:

```
export fi=Level2 export day=`date +%d%m%y`
cp $fi.tex OLD/$fi$day.tex
#clean  rm -rf  $fi.bbl $fi.aux $fi.blg $fi.dvi $fi.log $fi.pdf
latex $fi.tex bibtex $fi latex $fi.tex latex $fi.tex dvipdf $fi.dvi $fi.pdf
#okular $fi.pdf & gnome-open $fi.pdf &
```

Both the .bib and the .bst are in this directory.
natbib is loaded by default, but if I call the packadge I get the same result.

```
\clearpage \bibliographystyle{model2-names} %%
\bibliography{./Bibtex/global} \bibliography{global_scat} \clearpage
```

I use Bibtex in Linux insted of biblatex because I need to be able to run the tex file both OS without major changes to it.

Comment: Is bibtex recognized as a command inside a terminal?

Comment: It wasn't, I had two versions of latex installed, they were conflicting. now it works. thank you for the heads up. =)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was caused by two conflicting TeX installations.

Comment: Why would needing to run the same file on both OSes stop you using `biblatex`?